# Spark SQL - Escape Query String

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I can't believe I am asking this but...

HOW DO YOU ESCAPE A SQL QUERY STRING IN SPARK SQL USING SCALA?

I have tired everything and searched everywhere. I thought the apache commons library would do it but no luck:

> ```
> import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils
>
> var sql = StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql("'Ulmus_minor_'Toledo'");
>
> df.filter("topic = '" + sql + "'").map(_.getValuesMap[Any](List("hits","date"))).collect().foreach(println);
> ```

returns the following:

> topic = '''Ulmus_minor_''Toledo'''
>                   ^     at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.SqlParser.parseExpression(SqlParser.scala:45)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.filter(DataFrame.scala:651)   at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:29)     at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:34)  at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:36)   at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:38)    at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:40)     at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:42)  at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:44)   at $iwC$$iwC.(:46)
>     at $iwC.(:48)    at (:50)     at
>   .(:54)     at .()     at
>   .(:7)  at .()     at $print()
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1338)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
>     at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
>     at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
>     at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)   at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
>     at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
>     at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
>     at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)  at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:665)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:170)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:193)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:112)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

Help would be great.

j

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may be surprising but:

```
var sql = "'Ulmus_minor_'Toledo'"
df.filter(s"""topic = "$sql"""")
```

works just fine, although it would be much cleaner to use this:

```
df.filter($"topic" <=> sql)
```

Comment: Thanks dude. Pretty sure I have come across that syntax but not sure where.

Comment: It could be `df.filter("topic = \"" + sql + "\"")` as well.

Comment: does this escape double quotes also?

Comment: DSL syntax for sure. The first option I am not sure but I doubt it.

Comment: Whats the syntax for a query? var s = "John_\"Joe\"" sqlContext.sql("select * from topics where topic = " + s).collect.foreach(println) I have tried everything, I am getting a column/string exception using the DSL.

Comment: You can simply use triple quotes: `var s = """John_"Joe""""`

Comment: Ok, thanks. So I have to use a different techniques for each type of type of character? For Single quotes - "topic = \"" + sql + "\"" - For double quotes - var s = """John_"Joe"""". Is there not a way to escape for both with some method?

Comment: Triple quotes are the safest approach in general unless you want to match something like `foo"""bar`. In the case like you can usually solve the problem using [string interpolation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html). `val q =""""""";  s"""foo"$q"bar"""`

Comment: AHHA! I get it. The DSL is the dataframe query DSL. So I can rewrite my query as  df.where($"topic" <=> sql) and it escapes illegal characters. I am finiding filter very slow compared to a where clause for some reason ,that is why I switched. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @slotishtype using the DSL as opposed to SparkSQL is an excellent way to go for most cases, though there are some operations that can only be done in SparkSQL or using the underlying `LogicalPlan` case classes (there is no DSL). I gave an answer about general string escaping in SQL, since the title of the question is still about that. Last but not least, the performance differences between `where` and `filter` are due to external factors as they are synonyms: `def where(condition: Column): Dataset[T] = filter(condition)`.

Answer (score 5):

The title of the question is about escaping strings in SparkSQL generally, so there may be a benefit to providing an answer that works for any string, regardless of how it is used in an expression.

```
def sqlEscape(s: String) = 
  org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal(s).sql

sqlEscape("'Ulmus_minor_'Toledo' and \"om\"")
res0: String = '\'Ulmus_minor_\'Toledo\' and "om"'
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent for PySpark? PySpark has a `lit(string)` function too, but I can't figure out how to get an SQL-escaped string out of it (or if that's even possible).