# How to escape special characters in Spark SQL query, "`" does not seem to work

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in Apache Spark with some structs inside the dataframe schema. Now I want to run some Spark SQL query on this dataframe. So far I thought using ` to quote special names inside the dataframe works fine (which it did for names like "foo-bar"). But now I have a field with the name "fääär" and there the parser fails with

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
extraneous input 'ä' expecting {<EOF>, ',', 'FROM', 'WHERE', 'GROUP', 'ORDER', 'HAVING', 'LIMIT', 'LATERAL', 'WINDOW', 'UNION', 'EXCEPT', 'MINUS', 'INTERSECT', 'SORT', 'CLUSTER', 'DISTRIBUTE'}(line 1, pos 1503)
```

This is the part of the query it complains about:

```
SELECT [...] changes.`fäää`.`new` as changes_AL_fäää_new [...]
```

Someone knows what other quoting I should use here so that it will work? Other SQL statements with this type of quoting work fine (even though it's not required here), e.g.

```
association.`bla`.`deleted` as association_bla_deleted
```

If someone wonders why I want to do this: I want to flatten the dataframe to write it to an SQL database.

Comment: Use backslash to escape characters something like '\"\'

Comment: Heh yeah, looks like I found an answer already now, thanks for the hint :) see https://stackoverflow.com/q/31969047/1368432 (flagged my question as duplicate).